# Dynamic radio button generated using jquery is not working with unique name

Tags: jquery, dynamic, controls

I have created a set of radio buttons. On a button click i have created, the set of controls. But radio button selection is not working seperately for each individual dynamically created set. By using unique name ony we can save all dynamic row input in a single column by considering as single value.

**HTML**

```
<div id="InputsWrapper">
<table>
<tbody>
<button id="sitebutton" class="button big float-left blue-gradient margin-top-5x">Click Me</button>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="site[]" />first<br/><input type="radio" name="site[]" />second<br/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sign[]" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var MaxInputs = 100; //Maximum input boxes allowed

    var FieldCount = 0;

    var InputsWrapper = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input box wrapper ID

    var x = InputsWrapper.length; //Initial field count

    var sitefield = $("#sitebutton"); 

    $(InputsWrapper).sortable();

    $(sitefield).click(function()       
                {

    if (x <= MaxInputs)         
                    {
                        FieldCount++;           

                        $(InputsWrapper).append( '<tr id="InputsWrapper_0' + FieldCount + '">'+
                '<td><input type="radio" "id="one_' + FieldCount + '" name="site[]" />first<br/><input type="radio" "id="two_' + FieldCount + '" name="site[]" />second<br/></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" "id="sign_' + FieldCount + '" name="sign[]" /></td>'+
            '</tr>');
                        x++;
                        }
                        return false;
                });


});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST["save"])) {
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("sample",$conn);
        $itemCount = count($_POST["site"]);
        $itemValues=0;
        $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (site,sign) VALUES ";
        $queryValue = "";
        for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
            if(!empty($_POST["site"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["sign"][$i])) {
                $itemValues++;
                if($queryValue!="") {
                    $queryValue .= ",";
                }
                $queryValue .= "('" . $_POST["site"][$i] . "', '" . $_POST["sign"][$i] . "')";
            }
        }
        $sql = $query.$queryValue;
        if($itemValues!=0) {
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!empty($result)) $message = "Added Successfully.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with your code. I think You have to append the set of controls with table body.

```
InputsWrapper.find("tbody").append( '<tr id="InputsWrapper_0' + FieldCount + '"><td><input type="radio" id="one_' + FieldCount + '" name="site[]" />first<br/><input type="radio" id="two_' + FieldCount + '" name="site[]" />second<br/></td><td><input type="text" id="sign_' + FieldCount + '" name="sign[]" /></td></tr>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivek_aasaithambi/qwt1ks5f/) Kindly Check the URL:

Comment: Hi its not working. In the fiddel in first set i have chosen radio button first when i am chossing second in second set of dynamic radio button. The first selection getting vanished@Vivek Aasaithambi

Comment: It is because You gave same name to all radio buttons. Try using different name for radio buttons @RamaPriya

Answer (score 1):

check link:https://jsfiddle.net/rymgxfvh/

p

```
lease put following code on Your js file:
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var FieldCount = 0;       
        $('#sitebutton').click(function(){
            $(InputsWrapper).append( '<tr id="InputsWrapper_0' + FieldCount + '">'+
                    '<td><input type="radio" "id="one_' + FieldCount + '" name="site' + FieldCount + '[]" />first<br/><input type="radio" "id="two_' + FieldCount + '" name="site' + FieldCount + '[]" />second<br/></td>'+
                    '<td><input type="text" "id="sign_' + FieldCount + '" name="sign' + FieldCount + '[]" /></td>'+
                '</tr>');
            FieldCount++;
        })

    });
```

Comment: Its not working. Dynamic controls are not generating.. @mahesh kalantre

Comment: check this link:https://jsfiddle.net/rymgxfvh/  ,i check u r code is not working dynamically, in u r code you can select only one radio button

Comment: i check u r code is not working dynamically, in u r code you can select only one radio button

Comment: You have append the name field with unique identifier. By doing so i was not able to save it as a single input in a single column using php mysql@mahesh kalantre

Comment: create an array after that take length of array and use for loop for insert data into db